# What is the US foreign tax identifying number (TIN) for Israelis?

Tags: usa, taxes, israeli-citizens

I'm an Israeli citizen. I need to fill this form regarding some potential income from a US entity (It's the  W-8BEN form, "Certificate of foreign status of beneficial owner etc.").

On this form, there's a rubrique, Line 6, entitled "Foreign Tax Identification Number". The Israeli authorities don't ever tell you something like "This is your tax identification number". What should I put in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Israeli citizens, **the TIN is the Israeli ID number**; that's why you've never heard of such a number - there is no different, special number for tax purposes, there's just your ID.

For reference, see [this formal OECD document](http://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-identification-numbers/Israel-TIN.pdf).

**Caveat:** If you're a resident of another state, rather than Israel, for tax purposes - you will need to fill the information for that state, regardless of your citizenship.